# when proceed to checkout take very long and getting proxy error

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento-2.2.1

I have magento 2.2. so far work fine, but in the last week when I trying to add product to cart and click to proceed to checkout the page take very long time to load and after that getting proxy error.
[image]

If need more info please let me know